# JArray Deserialize only first property value to Object

Tags: c#, json.net, json-deserialization

I have this json file:

```
[
    {
        "blah" : "some text here",
        "hidden" : false,
    },
    {
        "blah" : "some other text",
        "hidden" : false,
    }
]
```

I load it into a JArray and then I want to use to ToObject method to deserialize the data to a custom Class:

```
public class LookupItem
{
    public string DisplayMember { get; set; }
}
```

the display member I want it to be the value of the first property that appears on the objects. So that:

```
var a = myJArray.ToObject(List<LookupItem>);
```

would return

```
a[0].DisplayMember  --->  some text here
a[1].DisplayMember  --->  some other text
```

I thought I could use a

```
[JsonProperty(Order = 0)]
```

attribute but it doesn't seem to be working for deserialization only for serialization. (the real issue is that I don't know the first property's key value upfront).

Comment: Relying on the order of keys within the original JSON feels *really* brittle to me. I don't know whether Json.NET even preserves that. If you don't know that key, do you know all the *other* keys? If so, perhaps exclude those?

Comment: Json maps don't maintain order. Any kind of display logic based on the first map pair would be unstable.

Comment: @JonSkeet I know the property name.. the big picture is I have a Json with the structure of the data and a json with the data. so the json with the structure has a list with string containing the keys that will appear in the and the data json file I have only the data. Also in a given array all the first properties have the same key (I will edit the OP).

Comment: Well if you know the property name, just use it. A [mcve] and careful, accurate description would make it a lot easier to help you.

Comment: @xDGameStudios wait a second, first you were saying your json is not consistent, and now you are saying it is consistent. Which is it?

Comment: sorry about that @CodingYoshi .. It is consistent but I don't know what the key for the first property is. I was looking for a nicer cleaner approach more like a JArray.ToObject<...> but I realize that is not possible so... I'll have to work around that, again sorry

Comment: So none of the suggestion in my answer work for you?

Comment: @CodingYoshi they work the second one I just have to read the structure json file (an array of properties with name and their type) and get the first property name and then use it in the Consistent JSON way you suggested :) thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Inconsitent JSON**

If there is no consistency in your JSON, you can deserialize the whole thing to an object.

```
var items = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject("Your JSON"));
```

Then cast it to a `JContainer` and loop through it and create your `LookupItem` objects. Code below assumes the first property is what you want:

```
var luItems = new List<LookupItem>();
var item = ((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)items).ToList()[0];
((Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JContainer)items).ToList().ForEach(x => 
    luItems.Add(new LookupItem { DisplayMember = x.First.First().ToString() }));
```

**Consitent**

If there is consitency, then create a C# class to represent objects of your JSON:

```
public class Class1
{
    public string blah { get; set; }
    public bool hidden { get; set; }
}
```

Then deserialize and create `LookupItem` instances:

```
var consitentItems = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Class1[]>(File.ReadAllText("Files/Json.txt"));
var consistentLookupItems = new List<LookupItem>();
consitentItems.ToList().ForEach(x => 
    consistentLookupItems.Add(new LookupItem { DisplayMember = x.blah }));
```

Comment: the real issue is that he don't know the first property's key value upfront

Comment: @محمدالنعيمي If that is the case, my first suggestion takes care of it. Please read it carefully.

Comment: You forced him to define a class corresponding to the current script.
What if the script changes to another type? [
    {
        "blahone" : "some text here",
        "hidden" : false,
    },
    {
        "blahxxx" : "some other text",
        "hidden" : false,
    }
]

Comment: @محمدالنعيمي That suggestion is if the JSON is consistent and does not change. I even put that part in bold font. Like I said, you need to be reading the answer carefully.

Answer (score 0):

using  Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray

take All JTokens

```
Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray jarr = (Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JArray)(JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(yourJsonScript));
List<LookupItem> myList= New List<LookupItem>();
jarr.ToList().ForEach(jtoken =>
     {
       myList.Add(new LookupItem(){DisplayMember=jtoken.ElementAt(0).ToObject<string>()});    
     });
```